# How to process shortcodes with post_id outside `The Loop`

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm reading emails using [postie](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postie/).

I'm using the following filter to process keywords inside the email and convert them into wp_postmeta items.

My [`postie_post_before` filter](http://postieplugin.com/postie_post_before/).

```
//look for ':keyword attribute:' tags and convert them to '[keyword attribute]'
function filter_content($post) {
    $content = $post['post_content'];
    $length = strlen($content);
    $pos = array(
        'name' => strpos($content, ':name '),
        'cost' => strpos($content, ':cost '),
        'price' => strpos($content, ':price ')
    );
    foreach ($pos as $key => $value) {
        if (false !== $value) {
            $content[$value] = '[';
            $value = strpos($content, ':', $value+1);
            if ( (false !== $value) && (ctype_alnum($content[$value-1])) ) {$content[$value] = ']'; }
        }
    }
    //if there is no name attribute then steal it from the subject line.
    if (strpos($content, '[name ') === false) {
        $content = ' [name ' . $post['post_name'] . '] ' . $content;
    }

    $post['post_content'] = $content;
    return $post;
}
```

My [`postie_post_after` filter](http://postieplugin.com/postie_post_after/).

```
function resolve_shorttags($post) {
    $content = $post['post_content'];
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    $post['post_content'] = $content;
    wp_update_post($post);
    storeDefaults($post['ID']);
    return $post;
}
```

Because I'm running `do_shortcode` outside of `The Loop`. `get_the_ID()` does not work. However I need the `post_id` in order for the processing to work correctly.

**How do I pass the `post_id` of the posts I process in `resolve_shorttags()` to the shorttag hooks?**

***Remarks***
I know this will get resolved if I leave the shorttags in and wait for display time and The loop to process the shorttags, but I want to process this data beforehand.

If there is a way to only process specific shortcodes or get the shortcode keys and attributes I'd be happy also. I can just call the handlers manually. What I don't want to do is write my own shortcode parser.

Comment: Have you tried to use call the global $post inside the function?

Comment: For now I've resorted to `$GLOBALS['my_post_id] = .....do work ... unset($GLOBALS['my_post_id']` but that feels like a very dirty hack.

Comment: It should work with global $post but i'm not sure where you calling the plugin